# Why am I getting a syntax error on my split columns?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (line 1, file "Code.gs")

on this code:

```
function Bullard Automotive(){
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1:A1000");
  range.splitTextToColumns(SpreadsheetApp.TextToColumnsDelimiter.COMMA);
}
```

Comment: functions cannot have multiple names - either use `Bullard` or `Automotive` (or remove the whitespace)

Comment: Thank you! I was very confused because its been working on my other uses!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by other uses? In JavaScript one cannot define a function with whitespaced name AFAIK